# updating magento table rate shipping method with thousands of zip codes

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, table-rates

I'm wondering if i can just do this or not .. did not gave it a try bcz i'm afraid this should not crash my server.

For defining table rate shipping, weight vs Destination, I do have `12,000` ZIP Codes, with each one having at least two shipping prices

Weight - 0-500grams - $1 - $3 (depending upon the zip/postal code)

Weight - 500-1000grams - $3 - $4.5 (depending upon the zip/postal code)

So is it just doable to have `24,000` rows in csv file and update them in database ?

P.S. I thought of defining state name with * in picodes and then having expictly those pincodes that have different shipping rules, but It doesnt seems doable, as State isnt a required option at checkout page, neither Indian States have a dropdown built in.

How can i achieve defining postal code based shipping without hurting magento database or performance .

**edit 1:**
Created list of states in db, but state filter can only reduce the csv rows to upto 7-8k not less than that.. looking for another level of filter .

**EDIT 2**
As per the Marius Suggestion, Tried updating some 1K Records at once and it works perfect. 
I guess when i upload another csv sheet it should update the existing records, or append the new ones. :-)

Comment: You can make state required and add the indian states, then you have a dropdown.

Comment: yes that is what i did (edit1). Now Batch uploading sheets 2-3k records /sheet. 
Will share the results :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My opinion is to use the default table rates shipping method.
Even if you get 24k rows, it's not like all of them will be loaded at once.
There is a select made based on the values you enter in the checkout and you only get one row.
Searching in 24k rows is not that bad.
The highest number of records I got so far for the table rates is somewhere around 10k and the website runs smoothly.

Comment: This is what i was waiting for @marius, even since i added states list, so 24k rows will reduce to almost half :-) let me give it a try

Answer (score 0):

You should perhaps consider webshopapps shipping matrix, this is a free plugin and supports shipping by postcode (UK) and Zipcode (US).  You can also uniquely label each shipping method at the checkout as well as being able to have multiple rates available for any weight/price configuration. http://www.webshopapps.com/uk/matrixrate-shipping-extension.html

There is a more advanced version of the plugin which also allows shipping groups, product groups and combinations of weight, price and no. of items. http://www.webshopapps.com/uk/shipping/productmatrix-shipping-extension.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Extension looks great, however it dosent seems to be serving States of India ? Does it ?

Comment: My 5 cents. There are many other shipping modules at the magento connect where you can define your shipping rules.

Comment: It does serve India, its a global extn and its free. And we didnt alter the download count on connect in order for it to get popular, unlike some other providers I could mention.

Comment: @Amasty Is possible can i enter weight as KG in webshopapps matrix rate, because Default UPS, FEDEX, DHL required products weight as KG, but i am using Grams for webshopapps matrix rate. Is possible can i use products weight as KG in webshopapps matrix rate.